# php regex help, removing a string that starts with [caption id=

Tags: php, regex

Need help with a regex. I have a big string of HTML and need to remove tags like this

```
[caption id="attachment_24612" align="alignnone" width="900"]
```

Each tag starts the same `[caption id=`, and ends the same `]` ... but what's in the middle will be unique each time. The regex code should look something like this, but I don't know how to pattern match the middle

```
$sourceHTML = preg_replace(array("[caption id=", ""),"", $sourceHTML);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To delete those *caption* tags, you can use this regex:

```
\[caption[^]]+]
```

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ZH451/1)

If your tags are on single line and you want to remove the blank line that the previous regex can leave, consider using this one:

```
\[caption[^]]+]\R?
```

The `\R?` part will match possible new line characters right after the tag.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ZH451/2)

**Example**

```
$sourceHTML = preg_replace("/\[caption[^]]+]\R?/", "", $sourceHTML);
```

Comment: The top pattern is extremely lean.  A quality creation.  Searching for `one-or-more not closing square bracket` (11steps,~0ms) outperforms a `non-greedy one-or-more dot` (62steps,~4ms) because the engine only has to check against a list with 1 character versus however many characters a dot represents.  I'll be using this optimization in the future.  +1 for best logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$sourceHTML = preg_replace("/\[caption id=(.*?)\]/", "", $sourceHTML);
```

Comment: edited to use (.*?) instead of (.*) to avoid unintended replacements

Comment: This answer's regex pattern is inferior to Niitaku's first pattern.  Note: `\sid=` and the capture group `()` are unnecessary.  Niitaku's successful pattern uses just 11 steps (~0ms) versus this answer which uses 113 steps (~29ms).

Comment: you're welcome  Luke, you can mark the answer as right & upvote to help ^__^